# Pivoting a data frame? How to declutter a 325x1 df

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

So I have a .csv of global marine temperatures at varying depths, but I'm fairly new to coding so I don't know how to handle this particular file. It is 325 rows × 1 column, with the first row looking like what the columns values would/could be? ie latitude, longitude, then the depths at increasingly large increments from 0-5400. I understand the way that someone could read off of it if they knew specific coordinates, but I'm hoping to plot it or possibly make a contour map out of it.

I learned coding with numpy and matplotlib so I am still getting used to pandas. Is this a simple reshaping or pivoting issue? Should I be changing the way the file is read?  I want it separated into columns that can be used for plotting and manipulating. Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/STaTf.png

Comment: Could you give an example of expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share a sample of your data instead of a screenshot. How do you import your dataframe?

Comment: I just did this, I'm not very familiar with the parameters yet.
t00mn01 = pd.read_csv('data/t00mn01.csv')

Comment: I guess I just want that first row turned into columns? I've been mainly doing scatter plots, line plots and contour plots recently, trying to find relationships between certain ocean quantities.